# PHP why is dirname() returning a dot?

Tags: php

For instance, let's say you have the path: `system/login.php`

```
dirname('system/login.php')
```

**Outputs**

> system

When you have the path: `login.php` (so without a directory in it).

```
dirname('login.php')
```

**Outputs**

> . (a dot)

Why does it return a `.`? And is there a simple way of making it that it returns `null` or `""`

Comment: A dot (`.`) means "current directory"; two dots (`..`) means the parent directory of the current directory.... this is a standard on many operating systems

Comment: Ofcourse! Why didn't i think of that?

Comment: For what did i get the downvote? Can you not ask a question anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as from `php.net` reference

### Return Values

> Returns the path of the parent directory. If there are no slashes in path, a dot ('.') is returned, indicating the current directory. Otherwise, the returned string is path with any trailing /component removed.

see reference - [**HERE**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php)

Comment: Thank you, little stupid to not think of that or find it myself.

Comment: its ok you asked out of curiosity. mark my answer verified

Comment: I will when i can, need to wait some minutes (-;

Comment: yeah sure, whenever you want :)